# Pycharm debugging from saved state

Tags: debugging, pycharm, workspace

Is there a way to debug a code in parts? Meaning, I wish to debug the code until a certain point, save the variables state and continue to debug from that point on.
Thanks

Comment: Did you find something helpful to share?

Comment: @Hamlett I wish :)

Comment: It's been another year. Anybody found something helpful? I would love such a feature.

Comment: It's not possible at the moment and there is no workaround.

Answer (score 1):

With its debug function, Pycharm offers a fantastic opportunity to see the properties of certain variables if the breakpoint has been set accordingly.

Apart from that, Python itself offers an amazing way to serialize and de-serialize object structures with its built-in feature pickle ([Pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)).

The pickle.dump(VARIABLE) command can be used to dump variables at a certain state into a file  or to be printed.

Sometimes I'm using pickle f.e. to dump a response variable into a file for later being used.

- Example Code

```
import pickle
import requests


r = requests.get('https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete')
#
# with open('assets/requests_test.pickle', 'wb') as write:
#     pickle.dump(r.json(), write)
```

With that you're able to open this file manually or load it with pickle.load (VARIABLE) later in your code to do something useful with it.

Comment: This is actually a great idea, also to shorten long debugging sessions where you wait for some particular situation that you observed before. Pickle the interesting state, and you can resume the session again and again.